# How to check the convergence in the collapsed Gibbs sampling of LDA?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, convergence, gibbs, topic-models

I am trying to implement the LDA model fit by collapsed Gibbs sampling by myself. I have go through this [article](http://www.arbylon.net/publications/text-est.pdf). And there is a clear pseudo code (section `5.5`), which states that I should check the convergence after each time iterate through all documents, but doesn't say how. Could you please tell me what is the criteria of the convergence in the collapsed Gibbs sampling? Thanks in advance!

NEWEST:
I have found this [paper](http://www.public.iastate.edu/~alicia/stat544/rr94-008.pdf), introducing lots of methods to measure the criteria of convergence. But I can't tell which one is suitable for collapsed Gibbs sampling. Could you help me? Thanks.

Clarify:
Thanks for @Greenparker 's help. What I need is the criteria of determining whether the sampler is converged or not.

Comment: The Cowles+Carlin paper that you refer to does not talk about when to stop sampling, rather it discusses the various convergence diagnostics. There is a difference between assessing convergence and stopping the simulation.

Comment: @Greenparker Thanks for your reply! So which paper should I refer to?

Comment: It depends on what your question is? Your question seems to be "how do you assess convergence of the Markov chain in LDA"? In which case this paper is fine. I was just correcting your interpretation of the paper.

Comment: @Greenparker Indeed I'd like to know how to stop the sampling in the collapsed Gibbs sampling. I had thought it was same with check of convergence. Sorry for the confusing. I'll change the question soon.

Comment: @Greenparker And I am still not clear about the difference. We have to check the convergence so that we can know when to stop, don't we?

Comment: Convergence of the Markov chain means that the chain has reached stationarity, and every subsequent draw will be a realization from the stationary distribution. But since MCMC is a sampling procedure, once the Markov chain has converged, the user needs to decide how many samples they need from the stationary distribution in order to make valid inference.

Comment: @Greenparker I can tell the difference now, tons of thanks. But which criteria should I use in the collapsed Gibbs sampling? I am looking around the code of GibbsLDA++, and can not find such procedure that they check the convergence. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not my stuff, but in general (1) clean up the title and question text (no one is helped by repetition, keeping old text, or comments of the form Why is this unclear?  (2) put clarifying text in the question you ask, not in the comments. (I can't answer specific queries on the substance of this thread.)

Comment: I don't know if it's particularly germane to this type of analysis, but a standard measure of Bayes MC convergence is the so-called $\hat{R}$ metric used, inter alia, in stan.

Comment: @C11H17N2O2SNa Thanks for your reply! I have read this method in the paper mentioned above, but I wonder what is the degree of freedom in this case?

Comment: The question cannot be understood as it stands, because readers are obliged to visit two links.  It looks like it could be an interesting and useful question if you could edit it to include explicitly the relevant information.